# React TypeScript custom wrapper around semantic-ui components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, wrapper, semantic-ui-react

I'm using typescript (Beginner) and trying to create a `Wrapper` function around some `semantic-ui-react` components.
This Wrapper will set my custom styles and return semantic-ui components memoized with childrens inside.
At the moment I got this error on my `Element` component :

`Type '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; }'`

Here is my code :

```
//Wrapper.tsx
type WrapperContent = PropsWithChildren<{
    className?: string
    [x: string]: any // All others props
}>

function Wrapper<T>(
    Element: ComponentType<T>,
    styles: string,
): NamedExoticComponent<ComponentType<T>> {
    const memoFct = (({ children, className, ...props } : WrapperContent) => (
        <Element {...props} className={classNames(styles, className)}>
            { children }
        </Element>
    ))

    return memo(memoFct)
}
```

```
//Grid.ts
import { Grid as SemanticGrid, GridProps } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Wrapper from 'ui/Wrapper'
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

const Grid = Wrapper<GridProps>(SemanticGrid, styles.grid)
```

After that, i'm using Grid component in my application with children like this :

```
<Grid stackable columns={2}>
    ...Other components
</Grid>
```

I saw working with memo and children at the same time can cause some problems on others topics.
Someone already tried to create a Generic Wrapper around some components ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an open issue of TypeScript, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28938#issuecomment-450636046

It's a workaround, but type casting the props spreading part should solve the problem: `{...props as T}`.

```
<Element {...props as T} className={classNames(styles, className)}>
```

But for your use case the higher order component (the Wrapper) doesn't look necessary to me. The code would be much easier to read and maintain if you use regular components and props. For example:

```
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';

// just use it normally
<Grid stackable columns={2} className={styles.grid}>
  ...
</Grid>
```

If you want to reuse it, just create a component:

```
import { Grid as SemanticGrid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';

const Grid = ({ className, ...props }) => (
  <SemanticGrid className={classNames(styles.grid, className)} {...props} />
);

export default Grid;
// If you want to memoize it:
export default React.memo(Grid);
```

There is no need to use any fancy HoC here. It's also unlikely that you need `React.memo` everywhere.

> Optimizing with `memo` is only valuable when your component re-renders often with the same exact props, and its re-rendering logic is expensive. If there is no perceptible lag when your component re-renders, `memo` is unnecessary.

(ref: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/memo)

So usually you only need to memoize a component when it does have some heavy calculation.

About the memo and children part, it doesn't "cause problems" but there is high chance that it's useless. If the children is a primitive value, like a string:

```js
<Grid>some string</Grid>
```

then `React.memo` does work in this case. `Grid` won't do any unnecessary renders. But if there is any element in the children, like:

```js
<Grid>
  <div>Foo</div>
</Grid>
```

Then the memo is useless, because the `<div>` basically means `React.createElement('div')`. And `createElement` returns a new element every time.